# Javascript malfunction

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

can someone explain me why this script is not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function destroy(ID) {
    if (confirm("Deleting is a very bad thing! Sure?")) 
    {
        location.href='@Url.Action("SomeAction", new { id = ID })'
        }
}
```

The error is: The name 'ID' does not exist in the current context, and occures here `new { id = ID }`
If I just replace ID in this way: `new { id = 3 }` it works fine. What is the problem?

Comment: <script> tag is enclosed properly.

Comment: The problem is,that you are mixing client-side and server-side scripts. '`ID`' is in javascript and its not  'visible' inside your server-side asp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mix your Server code with the client code.

`ID` is a javascript variable- **exist only on the client.**
`@Url.Action("SomeAction",` **server code, Exist only on the server.**

You can't mix them!

You can do something like this:

```
function destroy(ID) {
    if (confirm("Deleting is a very bad thing! Sure?")){
        var url ='@Url.Action("SomeAction")';
        url += '/?id =' + ID;
        location.href = url;
    }
}
```

You have to remember all the `@` stuff in the views are compiled and executed in the server and no longer exist in the client. tricky `razor`...

By the way, I would have change the confirm message...

Comment: thanks, almost worked. Changed url += '/?id =' + ID; to url += '/' + ID; and now its working perfectly. And, btw, confirm message is different: I intentionally changed it =)

Comment: @steavy. O.k. just be aware that your code works only because it uses the default settings of the routes in global.asax. (id is the name of the default parameter...)